# Problem in posting my questiom

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, re-open

Yesterday I have posted a question then I deleted today. Right after I tried to repost my question with a different title because somehow I wasn't specific.
The problem is that I can't post it anymore since the website considers my question as a duplicated one.
So how can I repost my question?

Comment: You want to repost the exact same question? I can undelete it if you wish. Is it this one: "Can we generate a model where the likelihood is proportional to Identity matrix"?

Comment: yes please that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: can I post it as a new question?

Comment: Why wouldn't you edit the old question? Are there answers to it already? Those would become meaningless, if the changes to the questions are massive, and in that case I would advice doing something else.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: either solution would work for me.
Now I'm looking to repost my question asap if you don't mind. Thanks!

Comment: @Bel: [your question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/360831) is back.